# Conditional formatting in Google sheets not working

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

This should be about the simplest thing to do, but somehow conditional formatting is not working in my spreadsheet.

I just want the column N value to be highlighted according to the rules on the right, ie. if the value is below the weekly target highlight yellow; within the target range highlight pale green and above the target range highlight darker green. For some reason, the highlight is always yellow when a value is entered regardless of the value.

What am I doing wrong? I've made sure all the values in J, K and N are numbers.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the equal operator in front of the address of cells

```
value is between =J3 and =K3
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it must be something simple I was missing!